# Swift flatMap and generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, flatmap

I'm trying to use flatMap to build a `Resource<T>` in Swift, but keep getting a strange error, and only works when I force the cast.

`Resource<T>`:

```
public struct Resource<T> {
    let record: CKRecord
    let parser: [String: AnyObject] -> T?
}
```

Working code:

```
public func buildResource<T>(resource: Resource<T>) -> T? {
    var dataJson: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    dataJson["recordID"] = resource.record.recordID
    for name in resource.record.attributeKeys {
        dataJson[name] = resource.record[name]
    }
    return (dataJson as? [String: AnyObject]).flatMap(resource.parser)
}
```

The code above gives a warning that the casts always succeeds, which is true. But when I try to remove the cast like so:

```
public func buildResource<T>(resource: Resource<T>) -> T? {
    var dataJson: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    dataJson["recordID"] = resource.record.recordID
    for name in resource.record.attributeKeys {
        dataJson[name] = resource.record[name]
    }
    return dataJson.flatMap(resource.parser)
}
```

It gives the following error: `'flatMap' produces '[S.Generator.Element]', not the expected contextual result type 'T'?`.

The parser is a `struct init` like so:

```
struct Example {

    let name: String
    let id: Int
}

extension Example {

    init?(dataJson: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let name = dataJson["name"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let id = dataJson["id"] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        return
    }

}
```

Any ideas how to fix this or a different approach? The idea here is to transform any CKRecord into a struct easily without needing to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Hall's answer is right but, by doing this, you'll be forced to change your `parser` init signature to receive `(String, AnyObject)`.

The best option would be to create another `init` with this signature and parsing it to your `json` signature's `init`, still being able to create this struct from a raw `json`.

```
extension Example {

    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let name = json["name"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let id = json["id"] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
      return
    }

    init (tuple : (String, AnyObject)) {
        var json : [String : AnyObject] = [:]
        json["name"] = tuple.0
        json["id"] = tuple.1
        self.init(json: json)!
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As you're creating your `dataJson` as a `[String : AnyObject]`, you don't need to do a `flatMap` on it, you can just return `resource.parser(json: dataJson)`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have the wrong signature for your parser function.  The entire json dictionary is of type `[String : AnyObject]`, but the individual elements in that dictionary when enumerated with `flatMap()` are of type `(String, AnyObject)`, not `[String : AnyObject]`.

Try changing this:

```
public struct Resource<T> {
    let record: CKRecord
    let parser: [String: AnyObject] -> T?
}
```

to this:

```
public struct Resource<T> {
    let record: CKRecord
    let parser: (String, AnyObject) -> T?
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this also result into changing the initializer of the `struct`?

Comment: @Victor  Yes :)  I wasn't implying that no other changes were needed, just that the error in the code was in that location.